# Problem with shared volume write permissions using minikube as a docker desktop replacement

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

So the problem is quite simple,

I want to use minikube with docker for the local development alone, without docker desktop app or kubernetes itself.

Everything works smoothly until I wanted to use a shared volume to persist changes on my local disk after I run `minikube delete`. My setup is hypervisor + minikube + docker on MacOS system.

To be specific, here is the commands I run:

`minikube start --no-kubernetes`

`minikube mount /private/var/services/:/private/var/services/`

`docker run --name redis -p 6379:6379 -v /private/var/services/redis:/data redis:5`

and the result of the last command is:

`docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/private/var/services/redis': mkdir /private/var/services/redis: errno 526.`

I tried to do the same with mongodb and result is always the same: lack of permissions to write to the shared volume.

If I change volume on docker to be somewhere else: eg.: `docker run --name redis -p 6379:6379 -v /tmp/redis:/data redis:5` – it works just fine

I already spent some time to debug it, like mounting minikube volume with another gid/uid, but no luck.

Temp solution, that I came up with is mounting to `/data/*`, but this approach works until first minikube delete command.

Please share what's your experience using minikube as a docker runner

Comment: The docker daemon exception states that is attempting ```mkdir``` of ```/private/var/services/redis```, which is saying that part of that directory does not exist on the mac. Docker will not have permissions to create a directory on the mac. Am I correct regarding the directory,  if so ,ensure that full path exists with the correct read and write permissions.

Comment: @djmonki path indeed doesn't exist (/redis part), but it's not my responsibility to create a folder structure for the service. If you replace redis with mongodb, it would still fail since mongo create multiple folder structure and many files inside. Also even if you create the redis folder, the redis service will fail to create a dump file inside

Answer (score 0):

Docker can't create redis directory in /private/var/services. You should fix permissions and ownership. Execute `ls -ld /private/var/services` to see permissions and `id` to see your current user.

Comment: on my local machine:

ls -ld /private/var/services
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  64 Jul 30 03:44 /private/var/services/

on vm (minikube ssh):

ls -ld /private/var/services
drwxr-xr-x 1 docker docker 64 Jul 30 00:44 /private/var/services

Not sure what I can fix here,

Comment: You can give to all users a permission to create files in the directory and test if it works: chmod a+w /private/var/services

Comment: Ok  there is some progress here, redis is up but still unable to create a dump file. Here is log from redis: 1:M 08 Aug 2022 15:55:58.567 * Ready to accept connections
1:M 08 Aug 2022 15:56:47.442 # Failed opening the RDB file dump.rdb (in server root dir /data) for saving: Permission denied

Comment: In that case I would create the redis directory beforehand. mkdir /private/var/services/redis

Comment: Then: chmod a+w /private/var/services/redis

Comment: Unfortunately thats not a case with mongo or any other service that creates/writes files/folders to the shared volume.

Comment: Seems like using docker desktop still a better choice as local containers runner